# Work with conditional groups in REGEX

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a pattern, but I could not fix my REGEX to work well.

I have the text:

```
REG1QA
```

And my regex is bellow:

```
([A-Z]{3})+([1-3]{1})+([A-Z]{1})+((A|B|C)|(D|E|F)|(G|H|I))
```

The rules is:
If my 4th charactere is 1 my last charactere must be A, B or C
If my 4th charactere is 2 my last charactere must be D, E or F
If my 4th charactere is 3 my last charactere must be G, H or I

How can I fix my REGEX to accept this rule?

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern `^.{3}(?:1.*[A-C]|2.*[D-F]|3.*[G-I])$`

Comment: I know OP didn't ask first 3 characters to be uppercase letters, but it looks like they should be (based on his regex in question).

Comment: @Jay - Who knows? If so, then `.{3}` should be replaced by `[A-Z]{3}` - everybody knows that :)

Comment: probably the same thing with `.*` to replace with `[A-Z]*` or just `[A-Z]` based on OP regex.

Comment: Works fine to me. I just change .{3} by [A-Z]{3} as @Jay has suggest and its works well to me. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this here:

```
^[A-Z]{3}(1[A-Z]*[ABC]|2[A-Z]*[DEF]|3[A-Z]*[GHI])$
```

I'm not sure if char 5 can be A-Z too but expected this in my example. So you have a common beginning with a switch for 1-3 and its rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Z]{3}((1.*?[A-C]$)|(2.*?[D-F]$)|(3.*?[G-I]$))
```

Comment: You should explain your rule. I know this differences but maybe not Marcio. The idea with the `$` is fine, but I don't beleve that non capital letters are wanted.

Comment: In question Marcio said nothing about characters in between from 1-3 number to the last character which should be capital cased letter, so I assumed, that it can be anything. Surely `.*?` can be replaced with `[A-Z]*?` if it matters.

Comment: Also if in between can be only one letter - `[A-Z]*?` can be simplified to `[A-Z]`, but it is not defined strictly in a question, only in example data, we don't know if other entires can be of different length.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @rekire - I think an explaination would be useful.